# Apache Spark Scala logging Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: EMPTY_BYTE_ARRAY

Tags: java, apache-spark, log4j, log4j2, scala-logging

Trying to add logging dependencies, I have a POM file like:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
  <artifactId>log4j-api-scala_2.12</artifactId>
  <version>12.0</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
  <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
  <version>2.17.2</version>
</dependency>
```

it gives me this error on runtime:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: EMPTY_BYTE_ARRAY
at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.ConfigurationSource.<clinit>(ConfigurationSource.java:58)
at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.NullConfiguration.<init>(NullConfiguration.java:32)
at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext.<clinit>(LoggerContext.java:74)
at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.selector.ClassLoaderContextSelector.createContext(ClassLoaderContextSelector.java:254)
at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.selector.ClassLoaderContextSelector.locateContext(ClassLoaderContextSelector.java:218)
at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.selector.ClassLoaderContextSelector.getContext(ClassLoaderContextSelector.java:136)
at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.selector.ClassLoaderContextSelector.getContext(ClassLoaderContextSelector.java:123)
at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.selector.ClassLoaderContextSelector.getContext(ClassLoaderContextSelector.java:117)
at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.impl.Log4jContextFactory.getContext(Log4jContextFactory.java:150)
at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.impl.Log4jContextFactory.getContext(Log4jContextFactory.java:47)
at org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager.getContext(LogManager.java:194)
at org.apache.logging.log4j.scala.Logger$.apply(Logger.scala:39)
at org.apache.logging.log4j.scala.Logging.$init$(Logging.scala:28)
```

but if i set log4j-core version to 2.13.2 it works fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By adding a new dependency log4j-api now it works fine with log4j-core version 2.17.2:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
  <artifactId>log4j-api</artifactId>
  <version>2.17.2</version>
</dependency>
```